# "selling pottery" or "by selling pottery"?

Tags: grammar, present-participles

> Quezada helped his village with the money he earned **selling pottery**. (From ACT )

Why is the present participle used here? Would it be better to say "by selling pottery"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figure out it myself from a more syntactic point of view:

> Quezada helped his village with the money he earned selling pottery.

"selling pottery" is a participle serving as an adverbial of manner as to how he earned money. So it can be rephrased as:

> By selling pottery, Quezada helped his village with the money he earned.

OR:

> Quezada helped his village with the money he earned by selling pottery.

"By" is optional and the participle clause can be put either at the begining or at the end of the sentence.

Answer (score 2):

> Quezada helped his village with the money he earned selling pottery.

Why present participle is used? - Because the action of earning money was continuous. It wasn't like he sold only one pot and got money for all of them. So it was in the past that he earned the money through continuous selling of his pots, and it was also in that past that he helped his village with the revenue he earned.

Secondly, your suggestion of using preposition "by" is alright. Either of the sentences is grammatically correct, and can be used satisfactorily.

[Google Ngram shows that 'earned by selling' is more common compared to 'earned selling'](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=earned%20selling%20%2Cearned%20by%20selling%20&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cearned%20selling%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cearned%20by%20selling%3B%2Cc0). However, a very noticeable thing would be that many entries of "earned by selling" appears in Mathematics textbooks more than literary fictions.

> The newboys in Washington were an exception; 22 per cent all that they earned selling papers on their own pleasures and amusements [...] [Source](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/Bureau_Publication/GMmByS9RkAcC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22earned%20selling%22&pg=RA4-PA196&printsec=frontcover)

> Not being an economist, however, means I do not know the difference between money earned selling chickens and money earned selling cocaine once the money is deposited in a bank. [Source](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/The_World_Geopolitics_of_Drugs_1998_1999/x2kcBQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22earned%20selling%22&pg=PA15&printsec=frontcover)

> Among those who contributed for the object was a little girl who brought in a penny which she had earned by selling flowers. [Source](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/The_Dew_drop_ed_by_J_K/tHcOAAAAQAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22earned%20by%20selling%22&pg=RA1-PA172&printsec=frontcover)

> [...] as a nonrefundable loan against any money eventually earned by selling Ray's story. [Source](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/Killing_the_Dream/IjYHl0Z0eAoC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22earned%20by%20selling%22&pg=PT40&printsec=frontcover)

However, interchangeability can't be done in every case. Like the last example sentence would seem awkward and non-understandable if "by" is removed.